# Setting UIPickerView Location in Swift 4

Tags: uipickerview

I currently am pulling data through a json api that is attached to a textfield. The textfield uses a pickerview to display the data. The problem I am having is that since I am doing this programmatically the pickerview is attached to the bottom of the view. I would like to have the pickerview display directly under the textfield instead of on the bottom of the view. I have tried to set the frame of the pickerview, but that hasn't worked.

```
thePicker.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: DropdownField.frame.origin.y-20, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: 300)
```

Any comments or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: set "DropdownField.frame.origin.y + textField.frame.size.height" to y in CGRect

Comment: I assume that you mean: thePicker.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: DropdownField.frame.origin.y-20, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: DropdownField.frame.origin.y). If so it changes the height of y and fills in the whole view. I want it to show just below the textfield and only be a height of lets say 300. Then you would see the other textfields below it.

Comment: Preferably I would like to do this [https://medium.com/@tharanit99/how-to-implement-a-inline-date-picker-in-ios-with-swift-4-9f8274460dbc], but with a uiPicker. @JD

Comment: Page not found @jfulton

Comment: https://medium.com/@tharanit99/how-to-implement-a-inline-date-picker-in-ios-with-swift-4-9f8274460dbc @JD